# Why cassandra write fails even when consistency level is met?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax, spring-data-cassandra

I have cassandra cluster setup with following configurations:-

- Nodes:- 3
- DataCenter:- dc1
- Replication Factor:-3
- Consistency:- LOCAL_QUORUM

I have created a sample spring boot api which recursively inserts in table(testing1) in keyspace(test).

Before performing write operation i have introduced delay(2100ms) in response in one of the nodes using tc command, so that when write operation is performed we get writetimeoutexception as write_request_timeout is set to 2000ms in cassandra.yaml.
Cassandra should still perform write operation successfully as required nodes to ack to met consistency level(2) are working without any delay but i am getting following exception:-

**com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 replica were required but only 1 acknowledged the write).**

Why is write failing even when required nodes to ack(2) are up and running?

Answer (score 3):

The write has to complete within the timeout to not get a timeout exception. Regardless of if the nodes are up.

> Cassandra should still perform write operation successfully as required nodes to ack to met consistency level(2)

No it shouldn't and wont. If the timeout has exceeded nodes may drop the mutation and rely on hints, read repairs and anti-entropy repairs to resolve it. The state of the mutation is unknown and returned as an error so it can be retried or at least not assumed to be applied within a quorum so that it doesn't break consistency contracts.

Comment: There is delay introduced on only 1 node,  other 2 nodes respond back in time. So why it got acknowledgement from only one node?

Comment: Either the 1 delayed node was the coordinator, there was a read repair, or the snitch picked that host for the DATA request initially and the speculative retry isnt setup to deal with it in the way you want.

Comment: If you want to make this not an issue, configure [client side speculative retry](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/speculative_execution/) on your driver. Also I would recommend the tables server side speculative retry to be `100ms` or something constant until 4.0 when you can do a hybrid retry.

Comment: I doubt speculation retry will help? as speculative retry will be useful if there are other nodes who can response before. but there are totally 3 nodes, 1 node is intentionally marked to response delayed. so only other remaining 2 nodes have to response in time to meet consistency.

Comment: Is it necessarily for the cordinator node to be up and running? As i am getting this error only when coordinator is chosen to be delayed node, otherwise write is getting successful.